# Debugging a site issue specific to a phone

Tags: android, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4, google-chrome, browser

I have a website which I hot on WinHost.com. In the past few weeks, I have found that 80% of the time, a page stalls while loading. That is, it never loads. It just sits there trying to load.

This issue never happens on my PC.
It does however, happen on my wife's phone too (Same network provider).

We both use Chrome, but it happens on all browsers.

I found a 'Phone Emulator' site, and have no such problems. It seems to load the mobile version fine. It only happens on my, and my wife's phone. The site is in development, so we're the only users.

Is there a way I can debug what is happening, on my phone? Like in the Desktop version of Chrome, I can F12 and see what's happening?

The site runs Asp.Net MVC4, with a Twitter Bootstrap UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the easiest way was to share my phones internet connection, tether my laptop to it, and run Chrome, pressing F12 to get the network traffic.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can do it by using the latest version of Chrome.

https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging

After connecting, just open the `Inspector` tool, and select `Network` tab in PC, reload the page to see what happen.